# How to properly secure private data in S3 buckets

Tags: php, security, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an application where I am storing users' images and audio. We use S3 for storage and I want to make sure that the user data we are storing is both secure and not completely accessible by the outside world.

Here is what I have thought of so far.

1. use pre-signed URLs with a limited lifespan so that the url in the browser will not be usable once the page loads.
2. Configure my bucket content to only be accessible via by domain - not sure if that will interfere with a user's ability to download their content.

I had the following questions:

1. Does using CloudFront to serve the files act as a layer of security since the url in the browser is not actually from s3?
2. Is it bad, security-wise, if the bucket name and structure is visible in the URL (if page source is viewed in the browser)?
3. Is it possible to configure s3 to use an alias for the bucket so that I can access the same content via a different URL and therefore not expose the bucket name?
4. What would be the best way to ensure proper file security while also allowing users to have easy access to their content?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> use pre-signed URLs with a limited lifespan so that the url in the browser will not be usable once the page loads.

This, or something very similar, is arguably the best strategy from a standpoint of security and practicality.  Your site generates the URLs when the page loads... or... the links actually points back to your server.  When clicked, your server verifies the session/authorization and signs a URL on demand, sending the browser there with a temporary redirect.

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: https://example-bucket.s3...
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store
```

> Configure my bucket content to only be accessible via by domain - not sure if that will interfere with a user's ability to download their content.

That's a really primitive tactic, easily defeated.  It's okay if you're trying to stop hotlinking to your content, but it doesn't qualify as a "security" measure.

> Does using CloudFront to serve the files act as a layer of security since the url in the browser is not actually from s3?

Well, not really.  The URL in the browser pointing directly to S3 does not really have security implications. See below.

> Is it bad, security-wise, if the bucket name and structure is visible in the URL (if page source is viewed in the browser)?

Not if you secure your content properly.  For example, I have a site where the user's "department_id" is clearly visible in the path to a file that is downloadable usimg a signed S3 URL.  If the user recognizes that number tries incrementing or decrementing that number to see reports from other departments, it doesn't matter, because they are not in possession of a signes URL for that other file.  Signed URLs are tamper-proof to the point of computational infeasibility -- that is, you cannot change *anything* in a signed URL without invalidating it, and you cannot feasibly reverse engineer a signed URL to the point that you would be able to have enough information to sign a URL for a different object before the heat death of the universe.  Of course, such a structure that embeds obvious/guessable values in a URL would be a terrible practice if the content were publicly accessible.

> Is it possible to configure s3 to use an alias for the bucket so that I can access the same content via a different URL and therefore not expose the bucket name?

Knowing the bucket name doesn't give you any paricularly useful information.  In a secure configuration, knowing the name of the bucket doesn't matter.  In certain scenarios, S3 error messages or response headers may actually reveal the bucket's name or location so this isn't necessarily always going to be preventable.  A CloudFront URL would hide the bucket name, but again this doesn't give you any meaningful protection, since a bucket name is not a sensitive piece of information.

> What would be the best way to ensure proper file security while also allowing users to have easy access to their content?

As above -- use signed URLs.

CloudFront offers a couple of additonal capabilities that differ from S3.

First, note that when a bucket is behind CloudFront, CloudFront can use its own credentials -- an origin access identity -- to sign the requests that it deems authorized so that S3 will allow CloudFront to access the bucket on behalf of the requester, and delivet the content.

You can then use CloudFront pre-signed URLs, which use a different algorithm than S3 signed URLs.  Two notable differences:

- unlike an S3 signed URL, a CloudFront signed URL can allow the requester to access more than one single object, for example, you could allow access to `https://dxxxexample.cloudfront.net/user_files/${user_id}/*` (where `${user_id}` is a variable containing the user's id, which you substitute into the string before signing the URL).  This would be something you might do as an optimization, to allow your code to generate the query string portion of the signed URL, which you could reuse in the process of building a page, to avoid the CPU load of signing many URLs individually in order to render a single page.
- unlike an S3 signed URL, a CloudFront signed URL optionally allows you to include the user's IP address, making the signature only usable from that single IP address.  You will need to balance this extra security against the possibility of a user's IP address changing while using your site, since that is less likely on desktops and more likely on mobile (particularly if switching spontaneously from mobile data to WiFi).

CloudFront also suports the same authorization capabilities of signed URLs, but using cookies instead.  If your entire site runs through CloudFront, this might be a useful option for you to consider.  Your entire site could run through CloudFront by pointing your main hostname there, and then configuring multiple origin servers -- both the S3 bucket and the app server itself -- and then configuring cache behaviors with path patterns to choose which paths are sent to which origin.

Signed URLs are the key to what you are trying to accomplish.

Of course, as with any security mechanism, it's important not only to verify that it works as expected, but also that it doesn't "work" when it shouldn't -- that is, be sure you verify that your secure resources are not publicly accessible *without* a signed URL.  If your bucket policy or CloudFront distribution is misconfigured to allow public access, or if you wrongly upload secure content to S3 with `x-amz-acl: public-read` then of course you have defeated your own security efforts.  The services assume you know what you are doing, so these configurations are technically valid.  Don't blindly follow configuration or troubleshooting advice without understanding its implications.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the amazing thorough answer @michael!

Answer (score 0):

> Does using CloudFront to serve the files act as a layer of security
>   since the url in the browser is not actually from s3?

You cannot say it as a security layer but it will not expose S3 bucket URL, because cloud front serves cached content of the S3 objects. If you use signed URL for cloud front then it adds security.

> Is it bad, security-wise, if the bucket name and structure is visible
>   in the URL (if page source is viewed in the browser)?

It is not bad to expose S3 bucket URL if the served content is public open to all. You only have to take care of applying proper policy of not making the put object access to the bucket open to world.

> Is it possible to configure s3 to use an alias for the bucket so that
>   I can access the same content via a different URL and therefore not
>   expose the bucket name?

Yes this is possible. Check this AWS documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html#VirtualHostingCustomURLs

> What would be the best way to ensure proper file security while also
>   allowing users to have easy access to their content?

Using proper IAM policies and granular access to user for the S3 content ensures proper security.